# Is the following sentence logically flawed?

Tags: logic

Is the following sentence logically flawed?

> If you are redistributing something that includes actual 3D product files, the TurboSquid files must be part of a larger creation and not in an open format that others can be downloaded.
>   https://blog.turbosquid.com/royalty-free-license/

TurboSquid files are 3D model files and **not allowed** to be downloaded by any game player, and the sentence seems to mean it's ok that TurboSquid files could be included in an open format that TurboSquid files themselves can be downloaded.

Is that sentence logically flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"not in an open format that others can be downloaded" should be "not in an open format that others can download" or "not in an open format that can be downloaded by others", otherwise I think it works.